# Embed app.icon still copies into publish directory

Tags: c#, deployment, icons

I have added an icon (using file browser) to all forms in my application. I have set its properties to "Embedded resource".  In the Project>Application I have chosen that file from the list. So it should point to that file. It does have "Do not copy" selected. However when I publish the app this file is always in the output directory and I do not know why. When deleted, icons are still OK. It is related to main icon because when I set application icon to default and let the Forms icons the same, it wont appear appear publishing. That is what I do not understand, because when selecting application icon, I assume this one is referenced and there is no reason why it should be left externally. Any ideas?

EDIT: The icon file is not in the Application Files list in Project>Publish.

Thank you!

Comment: You said publish .... is this a ClickOnce application?

Comment: By publish I mean just compile executable.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a ClickOnce application check the Publish tab in your project properties.  There is a button Application Files that lists which files are included/excluded etc....

Comment: The icon file is not here...I have checked it of course. And still it is always copied into the publish dir.